# Net Core - Dynamic Assembly resolution

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, assembly-binding-redirect

**Question:**

Is it possible to dynamically resolve dependencies in runtime for Core ?
Thus, not update the 'Api App' with Nuget package B v1.0.5 ?

In general, I wonder if there are a best practices for such cases

**Context:**

- the Package B v1.0.3 & v1.0.5 are back compatible
- It's known that for default Core dependency resolution, a root app ('Api App') should be updated up to package B v1.0.5 or higher, in in the opposite case there will be 'Could load 1.0.5 assembly exception during the Package A DI resolution
- Intention is not to forсe leveraging newest package B (1.0.5) to postpone possible regression testing

**P.s**
I've gone through a list of articles about the theme, but haven't find out if there any alternative to Package B updating. And my intention to avoid it, if possible

[image]

Comment: possible solutions are: to change app dependecy to 1.0.5 or change app dependecy package A to 1.0.3 (by geting source and recompile) (first could be possible without recompile the app if package B has strong name - so you can redirecting assembly versions)

Comment: I try to avoid the first approach (update package B up to 1.0.5 for root App) due to intention to avoid possible regression testing. About the second variant, unfortunately Package B is not strong named (publickey= null)).

Comment: You cannot have differrent verisions of the same library loaded twice in the same application domain **period**

Comment: thus, without strong naming it's not possible to resolving dynamically 2 version of a same dll in runtime for  an application domain? or set preferable version of dll for using